# rdlc report not getting rendered correctly on the server but looks fine on the development machine?

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, reportviewer, rdlc

I have an asp.net webform that display a report and this report looks fine when I view in browser from visual studio, but when I hosted it on IIS and accessed the webform it looks shrined up. I'm pretty sure its something wrong on the html but again another strange fact is that all the other reports look fine when accessed from the server, its only two reports.

When I view from browser (localhost):

[image]

After hosting it on IIS and I visit the same webform

[image]

Comment: I would start with looking at report margins and removing them all.

Comment: @InitK but my margins are only 0.1in, 0.1in, 0in, 0in you think making them 0 would make a difference??

Comment: Have you tried setting the display mode to PrintLayout? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.setdisplaymode.aspx

Comment: @HackGod555 Hey man. I am having the same issue on my part. Did you manage to resolve it? Since I was not answered here. Here is the link to my question, your input would be valuable. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711761/why-rdlc-report-renders-differently-in-different-environments`